# remote desktop mstsc with higher resolution

Tags: windows-7, windows, remote-desktop, windows-2000, high-resolution

I've got to work on old computer during christmas and I would like to work on my new computer with Windows 7 remotely using Remote desktop protokol.

Old local computer is running Windows 2000. I installed the microsoft remote desktop client (mstsc) on this comuper. The connection works but  I can only choose resolutions with ratio 4:3!!!

New LCD monitor with resolution 1920:1080 is connected to this computer. I would like to run mstsc in full screen mode.

I tried to run it from command line: mstsc.exe /h:1080 /w:1920
I tried editing .rdp file with changed session. But the highes resolution I could get is 1600*1080.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Better option is to text-edit(Open With... Notepad) the .RDP file for resolution (of HOST computer):

*desktopwidth:i:
desktopheight:i:*

It's a plain-text file.  You can define the resolution within. Define it for the *old computer's resolution.* Also make sure the line:

*smart sizing:i:1*

... is in there, unless you're cool with scrolling-about.

You can generally get RDP to do what you want, just dig a bit (and yeah, initially one wouldn't expect to have to edit .rdp files).

Comment: has to be noted that you likely can't specify higher than the host computer can provide.  generally the video-card specifies, but certain OS/'Windows Server' versions have hard caps.

Answer (score 0):

Best option I can think of is to download a Live-CD of some lite Linux distro, and try to connect with it.